# Поддержка китайских иероглифов в Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu

Возникла необходимость работать с китайским языком в текстовых редакторах.

В редакторах вместо иероглифов квадраты.

Как установить китайскую кодировку в убунту?

Comment: http://ubuntulyb.blogspot.ru/2011/04/ubuntu_03.html

Comment: вопрос, вроде бы, про отсутствующие в установленных шрифтах глифы (что решается установкой пакетов с нужными глифами, как уже посоветовали).  расшифруйте, пожалуйста, при чём тут «поддержка иероглифов» и «китайская кодировка».

Answer (score 1):

для отображения китайских шрифтов вы можете установить пакеты (согласно поиску слов "chinese fonts" в репозиториях дистрибутива):

- xfonts-intl-chinese — international fonts for X - Chinese
- xfonts-intl-chinese-big — international fonts for X - large Chinese
- fonts-cns11643-kai — Chinese TrueType font, TW-Kai
- fonts-cns11643-sung — Chinese TrueType font, TW-Sung
- fonts-moe-standard-kai — Chinese TrueType font, standard Song (non-free)